# Invertible matrix and division (Simplex algorithm)

Tags: matrices, linear-programming, simplex

My book presents the following algebraic construction:

---

LP: $z_{min}=cx$

$s.t. $
$Ax=b$

$x \ge 0$

Where A is a m*n matrix and x is a vector of variables.

---

Beyond the meaning of the simplex algorithm the book report the following algebraic steps:

$1.Ax=b$

$2.Bx_B+Nx_N=b$  Here A is divided in two sub-matrices A & B and x is divided in $x_B$ & $x_N$

$3.$ From the book:

"Multiplying the last equation by $B^{-1}$ and rearranging the terms, 
we get
$x_B=B^{-1}b - B^{-1}Nx_N$"

I don't get this step, it's seems that $B^{-1}$ is used like $1/B$.

I explain my self:

Back to the $Bx_B+Nx_N=b$

If I "divide" all by $B$, I get:

$\frac{Bx_B}{B}+\frac{Nx_N}{B}=\frac{b}{B} => x_B+\frac{Nx_N}{B}=\frac{b}{B}$

If I express $\frac{1}{B}$ as $B^{-1}$, I can write:
$x_B+B^{-1}Nx_N=B^{-1}b => x_B=B^{-1}b - B^{-1}Nx_N$
exactly the same expression of the book in point 3.

---

Is my explanation of the expression $x_B=B^{-1}b - B^{-1}Nx_N$ valid in linear algebra and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $B^{-1}$ is equivalent to $\frac{1}{B}$ **if $B \in \mathbb{R}$**. Or to be more exact, the $x^{-1}$ operator generalizes the inversion $\frac{1}{x}$.

Go back to your definitions to make things more clear. $B^{-1}$ is the matrix such that 
$$
B \times B^{-1} = I
$$
where $\times$ refers to matrix multiplication and $I$ is the identity matrix (with only $1$s on the diagonal). Now if $B$ is a scalar, $I$ equals $1$. And solving the equation $B \times B^{-1} = 1$ yields $B^{-1}=1/B$, indeed.

Comment: So this interpretation is valid only for R?

Comment: Yesss  Indeed :)